# macro to bring up a box, take an input and use that input to create a new row ms access

Tags: ms-access, macros

I have a form which displays ID, sales1, sales2, sales3. I have 2 textboxes for each, idtxtbox, idtxtbox2, sales1tbox, sales1tbox2 etc, the *tbox2 ones are invisible and I am trying to get rid of the ID boxes. The way I am trying to do this is, on formload have a box that opens up saying "Please input your ID" and has a box in which to put that. There are then a few boxes to input the amount of sales you have. I then want this value to read back to my linked table (SALES) and make a new row based on the ID and add the sales numbers available.

I have tried the SetProperty Macro with the following:

Control Name: idtbox

Property :Value

Value:

When I try to run this I am getting an error which states: "The SetProperty action or method failed because there was no form or report conext.

To establish the correct context for SetProperty, call OpenForm or Openreport before calling SetProperty, or call SetProperty from an event on a form or report.

When I dismiss this textbox I get an error which has Action Name: SetProperty, Error Number: 32602 and Arguments: idtbox, 10.

The actual macro is running as "updater:Form:On Load" (my form is called updater)

If you could advise me of how best to do this I would really appreciate it thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are going to want to do is have a popup form that you click first to access your data entry from. Create an unbound form and set the popup to "yes" in form properties. In the form insert an unbound text box (or combo) for your ID and a button. Program the Button with a macro to open your data entry form first and then close your ID pop up  form after. You're done with the popup. Now go into your data entry form in design view, click on the ID text box, on the data tab click on "default value" and enter in this code.

=[Forms]![YourPopUpFormName]![YourPopUpIDTextBoxName]


 And that should do it. From what it looks like, you want to create new records in a table, so that is where the data entry form comes in. Create a bound form based on that table to act as your data entry form. From everything else you need done, you should do a quick google search of "MS Access autopopulate form" and when you need to show linked tables, create a simple query that shows all of those values for a particular ID and then create a report based on that query.


On a side note, you might want to look into using better naming conventions. You will find that as you get more in depth into your programming, this will save a lot of time if you prefix all of your objects with 3 lower case letters. For example:

frmPopUp for forms

txtID for textboxes

cboSelectID for combos

qryFindSales for queries

rptQuarterlyProfits for reports

tblMasterTable for tables



And so on, good luck to you!
<

Comment: I'm having a little trouble finding any information on how the ID text input will auto populate a new row on the form, all I can find is how selecting a specific combo box input or text input it'll auto populate the rest of that form. I basically want it to do this: If the ID is already in this table matching the specific week, update that row. If not, create that row. I realise I haven't yet implemented the week, but that's the next step after this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use a combo to select an ID. And on that combo, have multiple columns that will populate their respective text boxes (or combo boxes).  Then in the On Change property of your ID combo insert the following code into VBA:
 
 
 Me.YourIDComboName.Value = Me.YourFirstTextBoxName.Column(1)

Me.YourIDComboName.Value = Me.YourSecondTextBoxName.Column(2)


 Remember that access starts count at 0, so your ID is actually Column(0)

"Me" is telling VBA to use the current form, if you are using "Me" in your data entry from to refer back to values in your ID Selection Pop Up, it will not work. There are 2 ways to do this, you can tell VBA to refer to another form besides the current one, or you can  use "Me" in the ID Selection Pop Up to populate other text boxes in that Pop Up. Then on your data entry form set the default values to refer back to the Pop Up as I have demonstrated in my first answer. You can easily hide these values on the Pop Up in layout view by making them transparent or white if you like.